# ddrescue prohibitively slow because of I/O timeouts?

Tags: ddrescue

On Ubuntu, my disk gave its SMART notification so I immediately tried to copy files to another disk.  That failed.  So now I'm trying ddrescue (partition to partition).  It is running ridiculously slow.  I mean it would be several weeks to copy this entire partition.

Each time it encounters an error, of which there seems to be many, it takes 1 minute to issue the next IOP.  That means that either:

1-the reads are timing out instead of completing in a second or so with failure status

2-the disk itself is trying for 60s to recover the data before finally giving up and returning failure status.

Does ddrescue have a parameter to be less patient with the disk?  It's heroic of the disk to try this hard to complete a read.  But taken collectively, it means I'll spend weeks on the bad blocks just to get to the good blocks.

Comment: #2 is probably what's happening. Check your kernel log (or dmesg).

Comment: BTW I had a different partition filled with photos.  I recovered most of them using foremost.  That went very well.